# How to import hadoop.hbase.mapreduce in Intellij by Maven?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I intended to use the pseudo-distributed mode of Hadoop in IntelliJ. Currently, I can run the WordCount example code successfully in my laptop. Then, I tried to write another code which includes the usage of hbase. However, I just cannot import `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer;` in my code. I tried to add different maven dependencies but it just doesn't work.

Here is the hadoop code:

```
package topten;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter;

public class TopTen {

    public static class TopTenMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
        // Stores a map of user reputation to the record
        TreeMap<Integer, Text> repToRecordMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //<FILL IN>
        }

        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // Output our ten records to the reducers with a null key
        //<FILL IN>
        }
    }

    public static class TopTenReducer extends TableReducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {
        // Stores a map of user reputation to the record
        private TreeMap<Integer, Text> repToRecordMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

        public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //<FILL IN>
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Here's my maven configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dataintensivecomputing</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache</id>
            <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anybody tell me what Maven dependencies I should add to the `pom.xml` file?

Comment: You really need to use a consistent version numbers for each group id

Comment: But that class is there for `hbase-mapreduce:2.1.0` https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/2.1.0/hbase-mapreduce/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableReducer.java

Answer (score 1):

As per Github source code, this is correct for several versions of HBase

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

It's not clear what actual version of Hbase + Hadoop you are running, but you should really make them consistent in your POM

```
<properties>
  <hadoop.version>2.7.2</hadoop.version>
  <hbase.version>2.1.0</hbase.version>
<properties>
```

Now, use those properties for the same `group.id` of each dependency, and run `mvn clean compile`, which shouldn't have any import issues if the classes do in-fact exist.

You can also enable auto-import for IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks！It turns out the HBase version is not the same as the one installed locally.

Comment: So, did you solve the problem by fixing the versions?